# Arduino extension for vscode - Syntax highlighting not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

i am trying to use vscode and the arduino-cli. The extension is working correctly in veryfing and uploading the code to the board but it keeps highlighting arduino keywords (e.g.: `digitalWrite`) as errors, and as far as i can tell this should not happen.
I am going to attach the `arduino.json`, `c_cpp_properties.json` files in because  i read that the problem may lay here.

`arduino.json`:

```
{
    "sketch": "first.ino",
    "configuration": "cpu=atmega2560",
    "board": "arduino:avr:mega",
    "port": "COM5"
}
```

`c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "cStandard": "c89",
            "cppStandard": "c++98",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: `digitalWrite` is not a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `c_cpp_properties.json` file lacks some statements. Have you generated it by calling the command `Arduino: Initialize` from the command palette? If not, strike the F1 key and type Arduino ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the paths of all libraries your Arduino IDE program comes with? Notice the line with the `forcedInclude` instruction that points to the path of the `Arduino.h` file.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/EEPROM/src",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/HID/src",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SoftwareSerial/src",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/SPI/src",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/libraries/Wire/src"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "ARDUINO_AVR_UNO",
                "ARDUINO_ARCH_AVR"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc.exe",
            "forcedInclude": [
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduion/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Arduino.h"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```